# Difference in appearance for text box using bootstrap in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, appearance

I am trying to get three text boxes aligned horizontally in a form and using the form inline class . It looks correct like how I want in google chrome but it looks too lengthy when I view the same in firefox. Below is the code and the images of how it looks in Google chrome and firefox.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group" >
<input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="100" value=1 style="width:100%" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="100" value=3 style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="100" value=5  style="width:100%">
</div>
</form>
```

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

What could be done to get the same appearance for both the browsers.

Comment: The spin-buttons will appear on hover when using Chrome, you can't do anything about it

Comment: @Psioniax but the difference in width is not because of the scroll right or is it ??